# Consulta directa tercera tabla desde tabla pivote

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Soy nuevo en Laravel y me ha surgido la siguiente duda. Tengo 3 modelos:

- Usuario
- Lista
- Producto

Tengo una tabla pivote con el ID de cada tabla/modelo ya que una lista puede tener varios productos pero cada producto tiene un usuario en esa lista, pudiendo haber varios productos iguales pero de distintos usuarios. Ejemplo:

Lista1 - Producto1 - Usuario1

Lista1 - Producto2 - Usuario2

Lista1 - Producto1 - Usuario3

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo traer los productos de una lista + el nombre del usuario de cada producto?

Los productos de una lista es fácil ya que "por definición" con un `Lista::with('productos')` se traen pero me gustaría que en cada registro apareciese también el nombre del usuario.

Pongo modelos por si ayuda, aunque soy novato y no sé si están bien definidos:

Usuario

```
    class Usuario extends Model
    {   
        public function listas(){
            return $this->belongsToMany(Lista::class, 'productos_listas', 'id_usuario', 'id_lista');
        }
    }
```

Producto

```
class Producto extends Model
{    
    public function listas() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Lista::class, 'productos_listas', 'id_producto', 'id_lista');
    }
    
}
```

Lista

```
class Lista extends Model
{    
    public function productos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class, 'productos_listas', 'id_lista', 'id_producto');
    }
    
    public function usuarios() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'productos_listas', 'id_lista', 'id_usuario');
    }
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: Entonces cada tabla trabaja de forma independiente y para relacionarlo esta la tabla pivot?

Comment: Agrega tus modelos y las relaciones definidas por favor

Comment: Hola! Exacto, cada tabla es independiente y tengo la tabla pivot con IDLista+IDProducto+IDUsuario.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendi de tu pregunta tienes lo siguiente

```
users 
id

products 
id

users_products //list
user_id
product_id
```

Tus modelos serian los siguientes

Modelo de usuario

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function products(){
        return $this->belogsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Productos;

```
<?php
namespace EmailTracker\App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, List::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo lista pivote.

```
<?php
namespace EmailTracker\App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProduct extends Model
{
    
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora si quieres obtener una lista de productos con sus usuarios deberás de hacer lo siguiente.

```
List::where('product_id', 1)->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Esto belogToMany está mal escrito

Comment: gracias le faltaba una **s** a **belogsToMany**

Comment: Hola! No del todo así, la lista es una tabla normal (ID+nombre por ejemplo) y tengo otra tabla que haría de pivote que tendría por ejemplo IDLista+IDProducto+IDUsuario.

Comment: Porque no compartes el diagrama entidad relacionan de tu DB para entender como se relacionan entre si los datos y poder armar los modelos y posibles consultas.

Comment: Hola!
Ya puse los modelos, pero para simplificar sería:
Tabla Usuario (ID + nombre)

Tabla Producto (ID + nombre)

Tabla Lista (ID + nombre)
Tabla Pivote (IDUsuario+IDLista+IDProducto+Cantidad)

La idea es una lista de la compra. Una lista puede tener varios productos, y cada producto de la lista está relacionado con un usuario.